# Implement a neutral element in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, null, shared-ptr

I made a bidirectional and 2-dimensional linked list. My nodes are called `chunk`s, and they contain a pointer to the `chunks` on their left, right, bottom and top.

```
class chunk;
typedef std::shared_ptr<chunk> chunk_ptr;
typedef std::weak_ptr<chunk> chunk_wptr;

class chunk
{
public:
    chunk(wanted_id) : id(wanted_id) {}

    chunk_ptr left() const { return _left.lock(); }
    chunk_ptr right() const { return _right.lock(); }
    chunk_ptr top() const { return _top.lock(); }
    chunk_ptr bottom() const { return _bottom.lock(); }

    void left(const chunk_ptr set) { _left = set; }
    void right(const chunk_ptr set) { _right = set; }
    void top(const chunk_ptr set) { _top = set; }
    void bottom(const chunk_ptr set) { _bottom = set; }

    int id() const { return _id; }

private:
    chunk_wptr _left, _right, _top, _bottom;
    int _id;
    void id(const int id) { _id = id; }
};
```

Now, let's imagine that I have built the following structure:

[image]

If I want to navigate from 1 to 4, I could use the following line of code:

```
id4 = id1->right()->right()->bottom();
```

Now let's imagine that chunk 3 has been removed, e.g. `id2->right == id4->top == nullptr`:
[image]

If I want to access `id4` then to perform some operation on it, there will be a runtime error. To avoid to perform a check at each step, I would like to introduce a neutral chunk element:

```
auto null_chunk = std::make_shared<chunk>(-1); // Let's define its id as -1
null_chunk->left(null_chunk);
null_chunk->right(null_chunk);
null_chunk->top(null_chunk);
null_chunk->bottom(null_chunk);
```

Thus, the following statement would run succesfully:

```
id4 = id1->right()->right()->bottom();
```

And then `id4 == null_chunk`.

---

However, I'm not quite sure about how to integrate such an element in my code.

I could use a **static variable**:

```
// This is a public static method
chunk_ptr chunk::null_chunk()
{
    static auto ptr = instanciate_null_chunk();
    return ptr;
}
// This is a private static method
chunk_ptr chunk::instanciate_null_chunk()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<chunk>(-1);
    ptr->left(ptr);
    ptr->right(ptr);
    ptr->top(ptr);
    ptr->bottom(ptr);
    return ptr;
}
```

Now, I would like to initialize left, right, top and bottom by null_chunk in my constructor:

```
chunk(wanted_id) : id(wanted_id) 
{
    this->left(null_chunk());
    this->right(null_chunk());
    this->top(null_chunk());
    this->bottom(null_chunk());
}
```

This leads to a a recursion stack overflow (null_chunk calling the constructor calling null_chunk etc...).

This forces me to define a specific private constructor for `null_chunk()`, but because I'm using shared pointers, my constructor must be public to use `make_shared`...

Thus, there is a design flow. **What would be the best way to implement such a feature?**

Comment: there is no "null pointer exception" in c++ when you try to acces a null pointer, your programm crashes

Comment: @Tyker meant runtime error

Comment: It sounds as if you will have to design a new kind of smart pointer (but I don't know them well enough to give a real answer).

Comment: How about just converting a chunk that is being removed to a `null_chunk`, rather than creating a new instance?  All incoming pointers still work; all outgoing pointers point to self, as desired.

Comment: This sounds like a memory leak waiting to happen; think *very* carefully about how you would implement a four direction linked list in such a way that you would: 1. Always have at least one strong shared pointer to each live element within the list itself and 2. Never have a cycle of strong shared pointers within the list itself. Aside from the *one* strong shared pointer, all other pointers to the node must be weak, or the main advantage of shared pointers, automatic cleanup, won't apply; you'd still need to manually break all the strong shared pointers when deleting, gaining you little.

Comment: @Lovy have you tried just making empty constructor construct null_chunk like chunk(...) : left(this), right(this), ... etc? That way you shouldn't get any recursion. Then you can make a static instance of such empty chunk and use it as you wanted with null_chunk.

Comment: And if you're following @DanNissenbaum's suggestion, and you pass shared_ptrs to users of your class for whatever reason (even hidden behind an iterator interface), you need to decide if it's okay that an existing strong `shared_ptr` could be destroyed out from under the holder, even when they share ownership (it might make more sense to make a new null chunk to replace the existing chunk to allow the outside`shared_ptr` to continue seeing the same data, though you'd probably want to disconnect it from the list, so it wouldn't allow further navigation.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I had a plan to replace left right bottom and top by `weak_ptr`s, because I store all the `shared_ptr`s that are currently is use in a `std::map`. So when I want to remove a chunk, I also remove the shared_ptr from the map, and -I think- there is no more ownership problem

Comment: you should define a neutral chunk entity in my opinion with a private bool ...

Comment: @Rochi and how would I set a bool to left, right, top or bottom then?

Comment: you keep same class object but you add a bool in it to check if is neutral or not ..

Comment: I edited the implementation, it is now using smart pointers.

Comment: Why do you need to be able to do `id1->right()->right()->bottom()` in one go? Should `id1->right()->left()` be `id1` if `id1->right()` exists? (hint: your current implementation doesn't require this). Should `id1->right()->bottom()` equal `id1->bottom()->right()`?

Comment: "Why do you need to be able to do id1->right()->right()->bottom() in one go?" For convenience? I have several situations where I need to traverse several chunks. And yes the two features you described should exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible to solution to implement the null node is to use a static member. This member is initialized once using another static function, that creates a shared pointer with the null chunk and redirects all outgoing connections to the chunk itself.

On construction of any other chunk all outgoing connections point to the null chunk as well.

As mentioned in the comments above, make sure not to leak any memory due to circular references.

You have to create a second constructor as you mentioned. However using a private struct as argument prevents any calls to this constructor from outside the class.

```
class chunk { 
public: 
  using chunk_ptr = std::shared_ptr<chunk>; 
  using chunk_wptr = std::weak_ptr<chunk>;

private:
  int _id; 
  chunk_wptr _left, _right, _top, _bottom; 
  static chunk_ptr nullchunk;
  struct pctor {};

  static chunk_ptr gennull() {
    chunk_ptr pnullchunk {std::make_shared<chunk>(pctor{})};
    pnullchunk->_left = pnullchunk;
    pnullchunk->_right = pnullchunk;
    pnullchunk->_top = pnullchunk;
    pnullchunk->_bottom = pnullchunk;
    return pnullchunk;
  }

public:
  chunk(pctor) : _id(-1) {}
  chunk(int id) :   _id(id), 
                    _left(chunk::nullchunk),
                    _right(chunk::nullchunk),
                    _top(chunk::nullchunk),
                    _bottom(chunk::nullchunk) {}

  bool isNullNode() const 
  { return this == chunk::nullchunk.get(); } 

  //
  // Further functions omitted
  //
}; 

chunk::chunk_ptr chunk::nullchunk {chunk::gennull()};
```